# Are Freedom and Lucky Patcher on topic for this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

Continuing [the question](/q/2321) about ethics, I'm worried if Freedom and Lucky Patcher, two "obviously unethical" apps, one of which allows free in-App Purchase by hijacking app's traffic to Play Store while the other hacks games and apps by modifying the compiled code.

<s>Fortunately</s> there isn't too many questions about Freedom, but it seems like there's already a few about [lucky-patcher](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lucky-patcher).

Should we help with those questions?

---

I can somehow remember that both F & LP aren't welcome on XDA Forum, and people there replying

> No Lucky Patcher here because this site is for developers.

Comment: If I may, XDA is with the developers and against the users. As previously stated, I do not condone slackers, but nobody here "helps" users but certain pirates.

Answer (score 2):

Not being a gamer I've never heard about Freedom, so I cannot talk about that. LP on the other hand has some very good and "ethical" features, but one can be very much tempted using a few of them in an unethical way (which is why I stopped using it years ago, after having given it a short try). It's sometimes a bit too tempting, so I have no clear "advice" here. Nevertheless, a *possible approach* could be:

- **NO** if the question is explicitly for the "unethical part"
- **YES** if the question is clearly on the "path of virtue"

That's quite "black and white", and the hard part is where to draw the line. As phrased in my bullet points, there's a wide "no man's land" in between which is likely to lead to debates on "why is this one closed and the other one not". So while I'm pretty sure about the "NO" part, I don't know if we should vote for the other half.

Comment: Freedom has broken down since Play Store was updated to 8.1. If you have a device with an older version of PS you can try Freedom.

Comment: @iBug no hands, no cookies – I'm not a gamer, as I wrote. But that's not the point here :)

Comment: As previously stated on the first question about ethics, there's no way to parametrize ethics itself. Any attempt to do so results in more censorship (XDA), and I don't think that we do need any more of it. For example, I used Lucky Patcher to patch WhatsApp, back when I used it, in order to protect my privacy while being able to see when someone read my messages. For someone, this may be unethical, but for me it was not. I propose that we let those questions stay; if one has the answer and wishes to write it, good for them. The system does already purge inactive questions after a while.